# FFMPEG: how to take 3000 snapshots faster?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got a video with the length of 200 minutes.
And also got the timestamp for each snapshot that will be taken.
I've tried to use ffmpeg to take snapshot with following commands.
However, it is very slow, and takes about 10 seconds for each snapshot.
Is there any way that can speed up? Thanks.

OS: win10; PC: Intel NUC8i5

> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:04 -vframes 1 000004.jpg
> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:08 -vframes 1 000008.jpg
> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:12 -vframes 1 000012.jpg
> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:16 -vframes 1 000016.jpg
> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:17 -vframes 1 000017.jpg
> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:20 -vframes 1 000020.jpg
> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:24 -vframes 1 000024.jpg
> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:26 -vframes 1 000026.jpg
> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:28 -vframes 1 000028.jpg
> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:32 -vframes 1 000032.jpg
> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:36 -vframes 1 000036.jpg
> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:38 -vframes 1 000038.jpg
> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:43 -vframes 1 000043.jpg

Comment: The timestamps are at irregular intervals. I've figured out one solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the timestamps are at irregular intervals (as appears to be the case from your example) you can use a select filter:

```sh
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -filter:v \
    "select='lt(prev_pts*TB\,4)*gte(pts*TB\,4) \
            +lt(prev_pts*TB\,12)*gte(pts*TB\,12) \
            +lt(prev_pts*TB\,17)*gte(pts*TB\,17) \
            +lt(prev_pts*TB\,28)*gte(pts*TB\,28) \
            +lt(prev_pts*TB\,43)*gte(pts*TB\,43)'" \
    -vsync drop out/%03d.jpg
```

This will grab the frame at the specified timestamp and if there is not a frame at that precise timestamp, it will grab the following frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try split video (200 min one) in [200 parts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-can-i-use-ffmpeg-to-split-mpeg-video-into-10-minute-chunks), then load one by one. Loading whole video to ram is expensive. Try with small video to see how it will improve

Answer (score 0):

I used VLC to solve this problem.
The basic idea is to use VLC's http interface to control vlc to jump to specific timestamp and take the snapshot.
The cosumption of RAM is very low, and the speed is much faster.
It takes about 16 minutes to take 3800 snapshots.

The below code is in autohotkey.

```
#Include, VLC_HTTP2.ahk
 
Loop, read, %A_ScriptDir%\TimeStamps.txt
{
    VLC_JumpTime:=A_LoopReadLine
    VLCHTTP2_Jumpto(VLC_JumpTime)
    Sleep, 100
    VLCHTTP2_Snapshot()
}
return

VLCHTTP2_Jumpto(VLC_JumpToTime)
{
    VLC_CurrentTime:=VLCHTTP2_TimeSeconds()
    SeekBackwardTime:=VLC_CurrentTime-VLC_JumpToTime
    if SeekBackwardTime >0    
        VLCHTTP2_JumpBackward(SeekBackwardTime) 
    else if SeekBackwardTime <0
    {
        SeekForwardTime:=-SeekBackwardTime
        VLCHTTP2_JumpForward(SeekForwardTime)
    }
}
```